# How to change node name in xml with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to change

```
  <Bureau xmlns="http://www.bbc.com/namespace" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    </Bureau>
```

to

```
 <Bureau>
   </Bureau>
```

For this I use nokogiri gem. Also, I get this xml from request.

I tried to make it with different methods:xpath,at_xpath.But can't replace it to node name which I need.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response)
```

Comment: You don't seem to be changing the name, but stripping the namespaces. `doc.remove_namespaces!` will do it for you.

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding doc.remove_namespaces! work for me